# Java: Convert between iterator types (interface / implementing class)?

Tags: java, interface, iterator, type-conversion

In a class, I have a container:

```java
public class MyClass implements MyClassInterface {
  private LinkedList<OtherClass> list; //Need to use 'OtherClass' instead of 'OtherClassInterface here
  @Override
  public Iterator iterator() {
    return list.iterator; //Problem!
  }
}
```

The interface:

```java
public interface MyClassInterface {
  //Is
  public Iterator iterator();
  //Should be
  public Iterator<OtherClassInterface>();
}
```

Then again, `OtherClass` also has an interface `OtherClassInterface`.
I want only the interfaces to be used by whom who works with the code.
The problem is that I want to use the full `OtherClass` inside `MyClass` but pass an iterator over `LinkedList<OtherClassInterface>` to the caller of `MyClassInterface.iterator()`.

I could not cast the existing `LinkedList<OtherClass>` to `LinkedList<OtherClassInterface>` inside `MyClass` to return the desired iterator.

How to handle such a situation?

## EDIT

### Reason why I want this behaviour

For another developer, I want to provide two interfaces: The first gives him access to a higher data structure which contains a lower data structure which he should access by the second interface. In the implementing class of the higher interface I use the type of the lower data structure directly, not over the lower interface.

As mentioned, the other developer wants to use both interfaces. Over the higher one I want to provide an iterator that gives access to elements of the lower interface - but not to the class that implements the interface.

### Additional needs

I also want the returned iterator to be "Iterable" i.e. so that I can use the "for each" construct. Is this also possible with *waxwing*s solution? If possible, I wouldn´t like to implement an own iterator - for me this seems not neccessary because I just want to give an iterator over elements of the interface instead of the implementing class.

Comment: better yet why don't your explain what you really want to achieve? there might be other/better ways? after all there are probably more solutions to this problem you're having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface can be defined like this:

```
public interface MyClassInterface {
    public LinkedList<? extends OtherClassInterface> list();
}
```

Then the implementation should look like this:

```
@Override
public LinkedList<OtherClass> list() {
    return list; //this is the container of type LinkedList<OtherClass>
}
```

This has the following advantages:

- When calling `list()` by an `OtherClass` object you will get a `LinkedList<OtherClass>`
- When calling `list()` by an `OtherClassInterface` object you will get a `LinkedList<OtherClassInterface>`
- The return value of each can be used in the for-each loop
- The iterator can be obtained by `list().iterator()`

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own `Iterator` implementation that converts between the interface and the concrete implementation when returning from `next()`

The problem with converting `List<OtherClass>` to `List<OtherClassInterface>` is that there is no way to prevent the user of the conversion result to put something other than `OtherClass` objects into the list (of course those elements must implement the `OtherClassInterface` as well)

Answer (score 1):

Can you define the interface like this?

```
public interface MyClassInterface {
    public Iterator<? extends OtherClassInterface>();
}
```

`list.iterator()` should be a valid return value for that method, even when list is `List<OtherClass>`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the interface?

```
public interface MyClassInterface<T> {
    public Iterator<T> iterator();
}
```

You can always implement your own iterator :

```
public class MyClass implements MyClassInterface<T> {
  private LinkedList<T> list;

  @Override
  public Iterator iterator() {
   return new Iterator<T>() {
            int index;

            public boolean hasNext() {
                return index < list.size();
            }

            public T next() {
                return list.get(index++);
            }

            public void remove() {

            }
        };
  }
}
```

didn't test the code